Unable to connect to WhatsApp messages in low bandwidth 22kbps uplink and 88kbps downlink from router even internet is connected
We are working on low bandwidth environment with 22kbps uplink and 88kbps downlink. Configured Router with iptables to deny all the traffic and allow on WhatsApp domains, ports and IP's.
We were able to connect to WhatsApp and send/receive messages in Android devices.
In Iphone, it shows internet connection as "on" but unable to connect to WhatsApp most of the time. It rarely gets connected and get the dump of messages at a time.
Can you please help me out in identifying the issue and provide fix if possible.
Our observation is that, Iphone might be trying to connect to some URL's for network connectivity. These might not be added in firewall to allow.

It sounds like a problem of a particular build of WhatsApp, so maybe talk to them first?
